# Can I change one angle of the wpf button rectangle to get a triangle?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have triangle button wpf. I am currently wondering if it would be possible to change one angle between the sides to 0 degrees. I define my buttons in this way:

```
    <Button Content="Button" Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Button" Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="135"/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Button" Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="225"/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Button" Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="315"/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
```

I would like to get:

[image]

Comment: A triangle-shaped button should have an appropriate Path element in its ControlTemplate.

Comment: I guess the bigger problem is to layout such triangle buttons like on the image, because everything in wpf is rectangular. Perhaps a special container?

Comment: So I cant do rectangle in this way? and I have to create all triangle shape.

Comment: @Sinatr I would test how will behave image in this button. I am still wonders or not at all to leave it as a square and just create a transparent background for the area that I don't care about. It is supposed to be a menu that pops up while holding the button and hovering the mouse over selects some options.